# Exclamation mark in .gitignore doesn't work

Tags: git, gitignore

I have this file structure

```
aaafolder
└─ bbbfolder
   ├─ filename0.txt
   ├─ dddfolder
   │  ├─ filename1.txt
   │  └─ filename2.txt
   ├─ cccfolder
   └─ filename.txt
```

I want all the contents of the `aaafolder` folder to be hidden, but all files in the `dddfolder` folder must be present.

So in the repository, I want to get in Git this:

```
aaafolder
└─ bbbfolder
   └─ dddfolder
      ├─ filename1.txt
      └─ filename2.txt
```

My `.gitignore` looks like this:

```
/source/aaafolder/**
!/source/aaafolder/bbbfolder/dddfolder/*
```

However, the entire `aaafolder` folder is ignored

Comment: what is "source"? I don't see it in your folder charts...

Comment: @DaemonPainter, aaafolder is inside source folder

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Per [the `gitignore` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), when negating:

> it is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.

This means that you'll need to ensure that the *parent* of `dddfolder` is included, *even if the contents* of `dddfolder` are not included.

In other words, you cannot use the `**` to greedily match.  You'll need to use a single-level wildcard.  You'll need to exclude folders leading up to `dddfolder` and then include their contents.

```
aaafolder/*
!aaafolder/bbbfolder
aaafolder/bbbfolder/*
!aaafolder/bbbfolder/dddfolder
```

Comment: But you *can* use the greedy wildcard match. Just follow it with a greedy wildcard directory exclusion, `!aaafolder/**/`.

Comment: So unexpected behaviour of git.

Answer (score 5):

Try it like this :

```
aaafolder/*
!aaafolder/bbbfolder/*
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to unignore every single subdirectory separately — `bbbfolder/` and `bbbfolder/dddfolder/`

```
/source/aaafolder/
!/source/aaafolder/bbbfolder/
!/source/aaafolder/bbbfolder/dddfolder/
!/source/aaafolder/bbbfolder/dddfolder/*
```