# .gitignore double star not working recursively from intermediate directories?

Tags: git, gitignore

Using git version 2.34.0.windows.1

I have a `/.gitignore` file at the root of my repository with the usual suspects of extension ignores in it (it's not really relevant here).

Halfway up the tree (`/a/b/c/.gitignore`), I have another file, where I wanted to say "recursively below this directory, ignore any directory called `devl`, except for one particular file extension directly inside".  So I put the following rules:

```
devl/**
!devl/*.dat
```

Unfortunately, it appears this does not work -- git still reports the file `/a/b/c/d/devl/test/foo.bar` as untracked, not ignored.  (It does not ignore anything at all in the `devl` directory tree.)

I was able to work around this by using the following rules instead, but as far as I can tell from the documentation, the above should have been legal and working as well:

```
/**/devl/**
!/**/devl/*.dat
```

Why is this?  Is it a bug or a misunderstanding?

Comment: There's a bug in Git 2.34 `.gitignore` matching. It is fixed in Git 2.35.0.

Comment: @torek Please repost that as an answer, if true; it's much more plausible than the other existing "answers".  But also please cite your sources -- as far as I can see the latest available Git version is 2.34.1...

Comment: FWIW, despite there being a comment about fixing gitignores in the revision notes for 2.34.1, I have confirmed that this version still has the same problem as above.

Comment: You have 2.34.0.1, not 2.34.1. I don't have 2.34.1 or 2.35 myself to test at the moment, though. I'm going by the release notes.

Comment: My last comment was after updating to `2.34.1.windows.1` which is the absolute latest at time of writing as far as I can see.

Comment: Ah, OK. Perhaps there are multiple bugs. The fix for 2.34.1 and 2.35 was to revert one offending commit, with a plan to revisit the idea again later: the code that broke things was trying to improve nonlinear (either n^2 or 2^n exponential behavior) for certain cases. The Git mailing list folks could use some sample `.gitignore` files as torture tests to make sure that the bug is really fixed and stays fixed, so if you can condense your case down to a simple version, and send it in, that would be good.

Comment: @torek [There is no bug](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format). Instead, we have all been led on a wild goose chase, and gaslit into believing we didn't know what we were talking about, didn't read carefully, making "wild guesses" and writing "non-answers". In the end these descriptions applied to the OP.

Comment: @Inigo: well, yes and no: `devl/**` means "don't bother reading subdirectories of `devl`" while `!devl/*.dat`means "do include files that are in `devl` and are named `*.dat`. But apparently Git reads `devl/test/` here. I'm not convinced the descriptions of `**` in the documentation are correct, myself (or perhaps the descriptions are the desired behavior and the actual behavior differs). I generally try to avoid `**` in gitignore patterns.

Comment: @torek, the issue isn't with `**`, it's with whether `devl/**` only applies at the level of its `.gitignore` -- i.e. `/a/b/c/devl/**` but not `/a/b/c/d/devl`. According to the rules that's how it works. See the link at [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70343709/gitignore-double-star-not-working-recursively-from-intermediate-directories?noredirect=1#comment124359529_70345124).

Comment: @Inigo: interesting: the reproducer in the github issue puts the `.gitignore` in `a/b`, but the question above puts it in `a/b/c`. That suggests that the reproducer in the github issue is not the intended one. A good reproducer is always important. :-) But yes, the question above has an `a/b/c/d/devl` so the `.gitignore` would need to be in `a/b/c/d` at this point.

Comment: If by "the reproducer" you mean the reporter, it is none other than @Miral.

Comment: The number of leading directories is irrelevant, so it doesn't matter whether the prefix is `/a/b/c` or `/a/b/c/d`, the important factor is the relative relationship between the gitignore file and the `devl` directory, which in both are always one directory apart, not the same dir.  So the two examples were consistent in that regard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you didn't read [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) carefully enough...

> If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular .gitignore file itself. Otherwise the pattern may also match at any level below the .gitignore level.

Your first pattern `devl/**` has a `/` at the middle, so it's relative to the directory `/a/b/c/`.

Therefore, `/a/b/c/devl/test/foo.bar` should be excluded, while `/a/b/c/d/devl/test/foo.bar` should not.

Comment: nice catch. I actually knew this too, hence my answer which worked... but got pissed on by @Miral because: (1) i didn't have time at the moment to analyze it, I actually have a life and kids to spend time with and (2) if I had time I'd have noticed looked right past his error (which is why I wrote "But I still haven't figured out why **/dev1/** doesn't." My eyes assumed he got that basic thing right). He pissed on another, "but you clearly do not actually understand the question; please do not just make guesses", even though he clearly did not understand the .gitignore rules. smh

Comment: btw, the second part of your answer is correct but doesn't apply to this case as  dev1 is not excluded and that was never part of the complaint.

Comment: You are correct that I overlooked that having a `/` in the middle of the pattern also excludes recursive matching (although that seems nonsensical to me, but it is what it is). So this is indeed operating as intended, even if it's a silly design. As Inigo noted the second part is not applicable as `devl` itself is never excluded.

Comment: You two are right about the second part. `devl` itself is not excluded. I misunderstood on this.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
**/dev1/**
!**/dev1/*.dat
```

The reason this works and OP's doesn't is because of the `.gitignore` rules, as [@lxvs correctly identifies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70346403/8910547).

Comment: This is not what is happening here.  The parent directory is not excluded.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these two things could help: Cache and Order.

**Remove the cache** of all or of specific file(s).

```
git rm -r --cached .
git rm -r --cached <your_file_name.ext>
```

**Change order**

> Each line in a gitignore file specifies a pattern. When deciding
> whether to ignore a path, Git normally checks gitignore patterns from
> multiple sources, with the following order of precedence, from highest
> to lowest (within one level of precedence, the last matching pattern
> decides the outcome):

This line is important: **the last matching pattern decides the outcome**

Comment: Possibly useful advice in general, but this is not the problem here.  No files had yet been added -- as already noted in the question, the files that should have been reported as ignored were reported as untracked, not added or committed.

Comment: @Miral merci for response. Have you tried this?  `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` Article to this command: https://web.archive.org/web/20090926065622/http://www.pagebakers.nl/2009/01/29/git-ignoring-changes-in-tracked-files/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
**/devl/*
!**/devl/*.dat
```

It worked for me and found the answer from [exclamation mark in .gitignore doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65776556/exclamation-mark-in-gitignore-doesnt-work). The first line ignores everything inside  `devl` and in the second line it is excluding `.dat` files.

Comment: This is not an answer; I already posted the equivalent to this in my question,

Comment: @Miral you are welcome, actually this time I tried it practically and mine worked with the following: 
`**/devl/*`
`!**/devl/*.dat`

Comment: please try the above or refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65776556/exclamation-mark-in-gitignore-doesnt-work) it can surely help you.

Comment: @Inigo you are right, actually after Miral said that my answer was just a wild guess, I started searching and testing for answers practically by creating a git repository. When I found the answer from the link in my answer, I edited my answer but after editing I noticed that you have already got the answer. It seems that I didn't refresh the page before editing to see your updated answer. I am really sorry for that.

Comment: @Inigo you are right about `**` , too. Thanks a lot for the point.

Comment: @T.H.Naseri no big deal. We all came up with the right answer independently because we read the `.gitignore` spec.  But we also were belittled by the OP while we were earnestly trying to help, and we all got confused as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure to *not* ignore folders, before not ignoring a file.

If a folder is ignored, no amount of `!myFile` inside that folder would work.

So for your second nested `.gitignore`, try:

```
**/devl/
!**/devl/**/         <=== Important
!**/devl/*.dat
```

That being said, this should be tried with [Git for Windows 2.34.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.34.1.windows.1) (Nov. 2021), which includes a regression fix for 2.34.0

See [commit 33c5d6c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33c5d6c8456ecb1e89450483586f5f3f115ffa93) (19 Nov 2021) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1bf2673](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1bf2673685990e0c9a5040d5289de3e7a5f9c96e), 22 Nov 2021)</sup>

> ### [`dir`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33c5d6c8456ecb1e89450483586f5f3f115ffa93): revert "dir: select directories correctly"
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Danial Alihosseini</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> This reverts [commit f6526728f950cacfd5b5e42bcc65f2c47f3da654](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6526728f950cacfd5b5e42bcc65f2c47f3da654).
>
> The change in [f652672](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6526728f950cacfd5b5e42bcc65f2c47f3da654) ("`dir`: select directories correctly", 2021-09-24, Git v2.34.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2d498a7c894444fba5cfb0007e6b757afcde63c6) listed in [batch #13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f443b226ca681d87a3a31e245a70e6bc2769123c)) caused a regression in directory-based matches with non-cone-mode patterns, especially for .gitignore patterns. A test is included to prevent this regression in the future.
>
> The [commit ed495847](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed4958477b28a1dd28597e40094e9a202a870379) ("`dir`: fix pattern matching on dirs", 2021-09-24, Git v2.34.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2d498a7c894444fba5cfb0007e6b757afcde63c6) listed in [batch #13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f443b226ca681d87a3a31e245a70e6bc2769123c)) was reverted in [5ceb663](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5ceb663e926bd22248d1d72d70fa701c558587ea) ("`dir`: fix directory-matching bug", 2021-11-02, Git v2.34.0-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/36f0a2e20f3eeeaef8c356a4c9d27c3a5a5e13d0)) for similar reasons. Neither commit changed tests, and tests added later in the series continue to pass when these commits are reverted.

Comment: That is different from what I want, and is not the problem.  But good try.

Comment: @Miral As far as I know, that does *exactly* " ignore any directory called `devl`, except for one particular file extension directly inside". Did you test it?

Comment: Your answer would also not ignore `*.dat` files in subdirectories, but I do still want to ignore those.  ("**Directly**" was not a mistake.)  If you remove that part, then it is identical to what I already posted at the end of my own question (and several previous answers from people who did not read that).

Comment: @Miral What you have posted does not whitelist folders. That is the all point behind my answer, and what is missed by others. You need to explicitly whetelist folders. I have fixed the "direct" part. Again. Did you test it?

Comment: What I posted **deliberately** does not whiltelist folders, because they should not be whitelisted.  It also does not blacklist the `devl` folder, so that the `*.dat` re-inclusion still works.  Did **you** test it?

Comment: @Miral But, my all point of my all point is, again, whitelisting a file won't work if any of its parent folder is itself ignored. That is how Git `.gitignore` always worked. And yes, I [tested it before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69970899/6309).

Comment: To put this another way: if what you think is the problem were actually the problem, then I would be asking why my `.dat` file was being ignored.  That is **not** the question.  I am asking why **nothing** in the `devl` folder and subfolders is being ignored.

Comment: @Miral Got it. I have edited the answer to include the regression fix from 2.34.1.

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be a bug in git; I have posted a [report](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3587) to their issue tracker.

Comment: Apparently [not](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3587#issuecomment-993629010).