# gitignore ignores the file I asked not to ignore

Tags: git, gitignore

Here's my complete `.gitignore` file for my Django project:

```
# Django Python Stack
*.py[cod]
*$py.class

# Django
*.log
*.pot
*.pyc
__pycache__/
local_settings.py
db.sqlite3
db.sqlite3-journal
media/
static/

# Environments
.env
venv/

# Visual Studio Code
.vscode/
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json
!.vscode/*.code-snippets
.history/
.history
.ionide
*.code-workspace
```

and here are the staged changes:

[image]

So the `launch.json` file I've explicitly excluded is still ignored:

[image]

What's the solution?

Comment: It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65777181/1256234).

Comment: I think you need to add `.vscode/*` instead of the whole directory if you want to un-ignore specific files inside of it. Otherwise it would not even look inside of the directory.